# I need my timer to go up every 30 seconds

Tags: unity, c#, timer

I wrote code for a jackpot to increase from one date to the next, and it works beautifully. The client wants the numbers to stay put for a while, and then increase.

---

This is the code:

```
if (timerRunning1) 
{
    timerValue1 += Time.deltaTime * 14.4 * (timerValue1F - timerValue1)
                / (finish1 - start).TotalSeconds;

    Jack1.text = timerValue1.ToString ("F2");

    //PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Jackpot1", float.Parse(Jackpot1.text));
    //PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Jackpot1f", float.Parse(Jackpot1F.text));

    if (timerValue1 > (timerValue1F - 0.1)) 
    {
        timerRunning1 = false;
        print ("ALTO");

        PagPrincipal.SetActive (false);
        Victoria.SetActive (true);

        Debug.Log ("FUNCIONA!!!");

        Invoke ("apagavictoria", 10f);

    }
}
```

---

I tried `WaitForSeconds(30f)`, and it didn't work. How can I make my timer go up every 30 seconds?

Comment: I recommend using a Coroutine for WaitForSeconds to work.

Comment: You say 'the client wants..', who is the client? Is this being created with the intention of being a *professional lottery game*?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, there are several ways to do this. `WaitForSeconds` can be used *inside a Co-routine*, but I would recommend simply keeping your own count, or using `MonoBehaviour.Invoke()`.

Each method essentially requires a class that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, but you *should* be doing so, regardless. You will also want a function that increases the jackpot. We will assume this function is called `IncreaseJackpot()`. All you need to do, now, is know when to call it.

---

## `MonoBehaviour.Invoke` and `MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating`

Let's take a look at [the Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/).

> ### [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).Invoke
>
> public void **Invoke**(string **methodName**, float **time**);
>
> ***...***
> **Description** 
> Invokes the method `methodName` ***in `time` seconds***.
> <sub>- [Unity API Reference: MonoBehaviour.Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> ### [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).InvokeRepeating
>
> public void **InvokeRepeating**(string **methodName**, float **time**, float **repeatRate**);
>
> ***...***
> **Description** 
> Invokes the method `methodName` in `time` seconds, then repeatedly every `repeatRate` seconds.
> <sub>- [Unity API Reference: MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)</sub>

Using these methods, you could repeatedly call `Invoke("Increase Jackpot", 30f)`, or you could simply call `InvokeRepeating("IncreaseJackpot", 30f, 30f)`.

## Keeping a Manual Timer

It is also fairly easy to keepbtrack of time using `Time.deltaTime` and your `Update()` function, as `Time.deltaTime` tells us the time since the *last* call to `Update()`.

```
float jackpotTimer = 0f;

public void Update()
{
    jackpotTimer += Time.deltaTime`;

    if(jackpotTimer >= 30f)
    {
        IncreaseJackpot();
        jackpotTimer -= 30f;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will add a section for the coroutine solution, when I can.

Comment: Invokerepeating worked fine, but now the jackpot doesn't have animation as it is increasing. Is there another line of code that I can add so that during a certain period of seconds it shows increasing the amount it gained in the seconds it was waiting?

Comment: @user94487, you would have to use the manual timer option and account for it in your logic.

Comment: You could find the "percent completion", for example, as `jackpotTimer * (10f/3f)`.

Comment: and where would I add that?

Comment: @user94487, wherever you want. Ultimately, we are not here to do your work for you. Going as far as accounting for how the bar animates, how the jackpot increments etc. goes outside the scope of your question, and I would argue such inclusions make the question too broad.

Comment: Rather than setting `jackpotTimer` to 0 if it's >= 30, subtract 30 from it.  This will avoid issues where the framerate is lagging and the time jumps from 29 seconds to 31, as well as truncating off fractions of seconds, making it not quite every 30 in the long run.

Comment: Quite right, @Draco18s. Cheers for pointing that out.